# Constraints on $\alpha, \beta$, if $\alpha f(x)^2 + \beta f(x) + \gamma \equiv 0$

Tags: analysis

I am dealing with an expression of the form
$$\alpha f(x)^2 + \beta f(x) + \gamma = 0,$$
where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and not identically zero, and $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are real coefficients.

I strongly suspect that for the above to always hold, the $x$-dependence on the LHS must be removed. This would entail that $\alpha = \beta = 0$ (and $\gamma = 0$ as a result). Is my suspicion correct? In case it is correct, is there an algebraic argument for why it holds?

Edit: I forgot to specify that $f$ is not constant.

Comment: You can solve the equation for $f$ and use the fact that f is smooth to conclude $f$ is a constant. Is there a typo?

Comment: Yes, I apologize. I fixed the question to add non-constant.

Comment: Constant unless $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$

Comment: We know that there are at most two values for $f$. But you require f is smooth, with some effort we know $f$ dose not exist.

Comment: What if $\alpha=\gamma=1, \beta=-2$ and $f$ the constant function $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is any non-zero polynomial and $p(f(x))=0$ for all $x$ then the range of $f$ is contained in the set of roots of $p$, Hence $f$ is a constant. Since $f$ is assumed to be non-constant the conclusion is that $p$ is the zero polynomial. This makes all the coefficients $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I figured that the correct approach was using properties of polynomials, but was unsure about precisely how.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equation as a quadratic for $f(x)$, and you get that either 
$$\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$$
or
$$\alpha = 0, f(x) = -\frac \gamma \beta$$
 or 
$$f(x) = \frac{-\beta \pm \sqrt{\beta^2 - 4\alpha\beta}}{2\alpha}$$

requiring $\beta^2 - 4\alpha\beta \ge 0$.  Except the first case $f(x)$ is a constant.